# how can i calculate if my motor can drive me uphill?

Tags: motor, torque

Well i'm building something on my free time and I want to buy an engine and I would like to know if it is strong enough to carry me uphill.
Is there a formula i can use?

This is what is know to me (added an engine i have my eyes on):
Engine (hub engine would be inside wheel):
 Volts - 36v
 Watts - 361w
 Torque - 22.83 N.m
 RPM - 151 n

body:
 Wheel radius - 15.3 cm 
 Body weight (with batteries, chassis, my weight and motor weight included) - 75 kg

Transmission:
Hub engine - not transmission. the engine itself spins and is located at the center of the wheel (i think this means that the differential is 1).
environment:
 expected to go ~35 degrees uphill

At what speed am i expected to go uphill?
 At what acceleration?
 How do i calculate this?

Further more, i found lots of engines that only state watt, RPM and volt. is this enough to calculate torque?

thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I'd say this was more physics than electronics...

Comment: Ben, please use proper English capitalization.

Comment: Any motor can carry you uphill, in theory, if geared down far enough.

Comment: @Nick: Yup.  After reading the title and the first line, I had enough of the OP thumbing his nose at us.  Downvoting, closing, and moving on.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't said anything about gearing so I'll assume direct drive.

Force = 22 Nm / radius 0.153m = 143N.

Gradient : 35 degrees.

Lifting force  = Driving force / sin(35 degrees)  = 249N.

So it should be able to power nearly 25kg up that hill if it doesn't have to accelerate.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no losses, it takes 750W to raise 75kg one meter/s (75*9.8~=750). So, with a motor about half that power your vertical speed will be 0.48m/s.

At 35 degrees incline, your ground speed will 0.48/sin(35) = 0.84m/s.

0.84m/s divided by 2*pi*0.153 gives 0.87 rev/s or 52 rpm, so you need a reduction ratio of 3:1, which agrees with Brian's answer that direct drive raises 25kg.

Comment: Worth pointing out that both answers make no allowance for vehicle or battery weight :  if you can keep the weight inc.motor and battery down to 50kg then 5:1 gearing would *just* do it.  6:1 or more would be required for *some* acceleration and friction, and even that might be optimistic.